# How to wrap handlebars expression in span tag, and make span tag clickable?

Tags: html, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

The datePick string is a computed property inside a button, you can click on datePick value to trigger an event, but clicking outside the datePick value inside the button does not trigger the event.

I tried wrapping it inside a span and giving width: 100% but still it is not clickable

```
<span>
      {{capitalize datePick}}
</span>
```

I want it to occupy whole space inside a button and make it clickable everywhere.

Comment: Please include more of your code especially the button and the event handler. Best would be a reproduction on Ember Twiddle or CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember Octane (3.13 Preview, 3.14+), you'd want to do something like this (based of @tehprofessor's answer)

in your template:

```
<span {{on 'click' this.showDatePicker}}>
  {{capitalize this.datePick}}
</span>
```

though, to use semantic HTML (and improve accessibility), you really want *buttons* for clickable things.

```
<button {{on 'click' this.showDatePicker}}>
  {{capitalize this.datePick}}
</button>
```

And then in your component's js:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @tracked datePick = '';

  @action showDatePicker(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('show the date picker');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding something like:

```
<span {{action "showDatePicker"}}>
  {{capitalize datePick}}
</span>
```

and in your component using:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    showDatePicker() {
      // Do some stuff to present the date picker.
      console.log('Showing date picker, eh?');
    }
  }
});
```

the `action` helper by default assumes the event is a *click* event according to the documentation:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-the-type-of-event

Comment: Attaching click events to a span isn't good for accessibility. At the very least this requires a `role=button` attribute and some CSS to ensure it gets the right mouse pointer, I think figuring out how to fix the original button is a better solution.